# Define is not defined (ESLint)

Tags: javascript, requirejs, eslint

I keep getting an ESLint error `'define' is not defined. (no-undef)`. I believe, I could just define `define` globally, but shouldn't this be supported natively?

A code example using define:

```
define([], function () { // Error here!
    'use strict';
    ....
```

This is my eslintrc.json:

```
{
    "env": {
        "shared-node-browser": true,
        "commonjs": true
    },
    "plugins": ["requirejs"],
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended"],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            "tab"
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "windows"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ],
        "requirejs/no-invalid-define": 2,
        "requirejs/no-multiple-define": 2,
        "requirejs/no-named-define": 2,
        "requirejs/no-commonjs-wrapper": 2,
        "requirejs/no-object-define": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't be defined natively because everyone has different expectations and requirements. That's why there's an `.rc` file so everyone can specify what their global requirement are for themselves. So, yeah, just add a globals section to your config file.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In your `.eslintrc.json` set:

```
"env": {
    "amd": true
},
```

When the "amd" environment is turned on, eslint registers globals for `define` and `require`.

I would also turn off the `"commonjs"` environment unless you really are mixing both AMD and CommonJS in the same code base.

Comment: is this specifically for AMD CPUS?